# Recycle View not working inside ScrollView/NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

In My application, I have Recycle View in Scroll View. Here is my View XML Hierarachy

```
<LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView>
            <LinearLayout>
                <CardView>
                <CardView>
                <CardView>
                <CardView>
                <CardView>
                <RecyclerView> -- With Horizontal Scrolling
                    <CardView>
                    <CardView>
                    <CardView>
                </RecyclerView>
            <LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is My Recycle View Code

```
RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_images);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

        rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

But my Recycle View doesn't appear. If I remove Scroll View, I cant see Recycler view as my screen shows only first few Cards, only. I tried to use NestedScrollView but even that is not working. Please check attached mockup to understand what I am trying to achieve. Height of my Cards is not fixed So I cant make my RecycleView Height fixed.[image: Mockup]

Comment: can you paste your xml layout code in the question?

Comment: you need a RecyclerView.Adapter. And should populate views from the adapter. I'm not sure if you can just nest the views inside the RecyclerView tag. Try with adapter

Comment: Yea, like @hello_world said you have to load the content with the adapter, even if they are static(always there). A RecyclerView is an advanced ListView so you cant place content in through XML unless you have a layout specifically for the RecyclerView.

Comment: @Frank in Recycler View I am loading content by RecylerAdapter only.

Comment: Would a simple horizontal linear layout work for your needs? Its not ideal for performance to have multiple levels of layout nesting but it may work.

Comment: @Frank But Horizontal Linear Layout doesnt show scroll bar.

Comment: @Alex if its in a ScrollView it does.

Comment: I have an issue, where the RecycleView is inside a NestedScrollview. I can't use recycleview.scrollToPosition(X); , it just doesn't work. I tried everything in the last 6 days, but I can get over it. any suggestion? I would be very thankful !

Answer (score 1):

use CoordinatorLayout as parent of the xml then it will work

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```